# I want to report as a spam (unpublish) this blog in search engines

Tags: spam

I want to report a site as spam (unpublish) this blog in search engines. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: -1 Why? It's not the best blog in the world, but doesn't appear to be spam in any obvious way.

Answer (score 1):

Do you own the blog ? If so i beleve you can just deactivate you account in blogspot. Another option would be to edit the html of the site and a meta noidex tags to the pages.

If its not your site things are a little bit more difficult the only thing i think of would be to try and get the content removed under the 'abuse' rules of blogspot.

For more on that see here - http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=76315

Answer (score 1):

Google accepts reports of websites spamming the search engine with paid links here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/paidlinks